# docker oomkiller vs malloc failure from within the container

Tags: docker, memory, out-of-memory

I wrote a short java program to allocate memory:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static final int SIZE_NATIVE_LONG_IN_BYTE = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer memoryConsumptionInMiB = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        List<long[][]> foo = new ArrayList<long[][]>();
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(i++);
            foo.add(new long[(1024 / SIZE_NATIVE_LONG_IN_BYTE * 1024)][memoryConsumptionInMiB]);
        }
    }
}
```

i then try to run it within a docker container with several different parameters:

1. Xmx 1G and docker container without memory limits
2. Xmx 1G and docker run -m 512m
3. Xmx 1G and docker run -m 512m --disable-oom-killer

**this is how i run the program (in case of 3):**

**(edit: uploaded a prepared image with above class)**

```
docker run -it --oom-kill-disable -m 512m kazesberger/alpine-java-memory-tester java -classpath . com.company.Main 10 (~Megabytes allocated per iteration)
```

my expectation was:

1. OutOfMemory (Heap) at 1G
2. host OS kills docker container (proofable with docker inspect or kernel log) before the actual OutOfMemory Error happens.
3. malloc within docker container fails and results in jvm terminating with some kind of OutOfMemoryError.

actual results:

1. expectation met
2. expectation met
3. oomkiller still killing the container. docker inspect still shows OOMKilled true

so you see my actual goal isn't really to suppress oomKiller in fulfilling its purpose. It's rather my goal to have the processes within the container fail allocating memory they're not allowed to.

**Preconditions/Versions:**
swapoff -a

docker --version
Docker version 17.11.0-ce-rc4, build 587f1f0

docker run -it kazesberger/alpine-java-memory-tester java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111-internal"

Comment: Do you have a public image with this test application that we could run along with the full Docker commands so we can confirm the behavior?

Comment: thx for your repoly @AndyShinn. i built a small public image and updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is incorrect. `--oom-kill-disable` does not disable virtual memory overcommitment, which would cause `malloc` to fail if `mmap` fails to allocate requested pages. Instead, the option maps to the [cgroup v1 feature](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) exposed via sysfs (`/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/<id>/memory.oom_control`) and causes tasks requesting memory beyond the limit to block until either memory is freed or limits change.

`--oom-kill-disable` requires cgroup v1. So, the first requirements is that your docker installation uses cgroup v1:

```
$ docker system info | grep -i Cg 
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
```

If that's the case, `--oom-kill-disable` should be available. You can confirm that the cgroup option was set by docker using sysfs:

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/<id>/memory.oom_control
oom_kill_disable 1
under_oom 1
oom_kill 0
```

If `oom_kill_disable` is not set, your version of docker docker failed to set the option.
`under_oom` indicates that the limit was reached and tasks wait for available memory.

The proc filesystem can be used to confirm that tasks are indeed waiting for available memory:

```
$ cat /proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xbc/0xd4
[<0>] mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0xf0/0x158
[<0>] pagefault_out_of_memory+0x44/0x1b8
[<0>] do_page_fault+0x254/0x388
[<0>] do_translation_fault+0x54/0x74
[<0>] do_mem_abort+0x58/0xb4
[<0>] el0_ia+0x54/0x68
[<0>] el0_sync_handler+0x15c/0x1c4
[<0>] el0_sync+0x180/0x1c0
```

In my test installation (Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57, Linux 5.10.76), I forced docker to use cgroup v1 by updating `settings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "deprecatedCgroupv1": true
}
```

With cgroup v2, starting the container triggers the following warning:

```
WARNING: Your kernel does not support OomKillDisable. OomKillDisable discarded.
```

cgroup v2 does not provide an `oom_kill_disable` equivalent.

What you desire is the behavior of `vm.overcommit_memory = 2` (or `0` as a compromise) at the cgroup level. Setting that on the host level to disable overcommitment results in the behavior you expected:

```
$ docker run -it  -m 512m test java -Xms32g -Xmx32g Main
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000fff785400000, 11453202432, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 11453202432 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid1.log
```

Unfortunately, AFAIK that facility does not exist as of today.